# How are UV coordinates measured?

Tags: 3d, textures, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

I've got a 3D modeling program exporting a UV mapped 3D model.

However the UV coordinates seem to be invalid or using a system I don't understand. I need help in understanding how UV coordinates map to the pixels of the bitmap (X, Y)

I've got a couple of textures in the range of 150x100 to 200x600. Here are some extracts:

```
    vt 1.04017 2.60853

    vt -208.397 776.637

    vt -0.984585 -0.0106576

    vt -208.397 32.6369
```

Based on the above data, considering the maximum measurable pixel is 600, are the 700+ UV coordinates wrapping back to the start of the image? And are the <0 UV coordinates measuring from the end of the image backward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those values repeat the same image. Wrapping mode can be controlled in your code.

Comment: Well, I've got many UV coordinates clearly in the range 0-1 and many coords in seemingly pixel values in the range 100-300. How do I know which one to interpret the coordinates as? Is there a standard or system for this?

Comment: The convention is that UVs are in the range 0 to 1, inclusive. Deviating from that convention by using numbers outside of the range happens, but the exactly meaning of the values then usually becomes context-specific. Pixels are a good guess though.